# jQuery - How can I have the action of a form be to display in same div in which the form is?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have three pages `new.html`, `somepage.html`, and `someotherpage.html`

**new.html**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#nav a').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $('#content').load($(this).attr('href'));
  });
 });
</script>

<div id="nav"><a href="somepage.html">Some page</a></div>

<div id="content">show the stuff</div>
```

When clicking on the `somepage.html` link, it is displayed in `div` having id `content`.

**somepage.html**

```
<form id="form" action="someotherpage.html" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="test"/>
</form>
```

---

The action of the form goes to a new page, whereas I want it to be in the same `div` only where the actual form was.

Comment: Unless you have some URL rewriting going on or changed some php.ini settings, processing a form with a `.html` isn't going to go well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to do something very similar as you the first page, load `someotherpage.html` in a sibling of your form :

```
somepage.html :

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
$('#form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#target').load($(this).attr('action'));
});
</script>

<div id="formWrapper">
    <form id="form" action="someotherpage.html" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="test"/>
    </form>
    <div id="target"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works well but now the issue is that the data of the form is not posted. for ex. if the form has some input type text, on submitting the form, the value entered in the input box is not posted and shows as undefined index error?